# I obtained the graph using torch.fx. How to split the graph and place it on different GPUs?

Tags: pytorch, distributed

how to auto split the graph.For example Resnet?

I have got the graph of Resnet traced by torch.fx.How can i get the subgraphs and place them in different gpus. What should I learn to solve the Problem.

I'm a newbie, please give me some advice.Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.